# Old PHP code ':=' operator?

Tags: php, sql, operators

I am going through an older php application with some functional issues.  I came across the following code that appears to be designed to reset the ids in a table:

```
    SET @num := 0;
    UPDATE `pop_table` SET id = @num := (@num+1);
    ALTER TABLE `pop_table` AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

So... what in the world is an ':=' operator for?? - and what would be the alternative in this particular snippet?

I've searched here, php.net, google, apparently ":=" is either to small or too obscure to find, or I just don't know how to commit a proper search for it.  Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: This is not PHP code.

Comment: That is SQL. It may well be embedded within PHP (probably as a string), but it is not PHP.

Comment: I cannot disagree - as it certainly doesn't work, and based on your response likely never worked - but nonetheless someone decided to place this into a .php file as standalone code, right in the middle of what appears to be normal code - but of course the file itself fails as a result. I would like to modify it to the proper php alternative...

Comment: @Jocelyn: Your edit of the tags is bogus. This question is NOT about the `:=` operator in SQL. It is about the `:=` operator in PHP. As it has been shown, this operator doesn't exist in PHP, but that fact can only be known if you know PHP, so you want someone with PHP experience looking at this question, hence the PHP tag is perfectly valid!

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I disagree. The code in the question is not PHP code. Indeed, it is enclosed in a PHP file. You may also find HTML, XML, CSS and many more languages in a PHP file. The question is about the `:=`, which is an SQL/MySQL operator.

Comment: @Jocelyn: As an SQL guy knowing nothing about PHP you can't know whether this is valid in a PHP file or not. That's why the PHP tag is required here.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth and Jocelyn As someone who knows SQL and PHP, I can tell that it is definitely SQL, and not PHP.

Comment: Tags describe a question, not its answers. If the code is not PHP but a different language, point that out in a comment or an answer. If the OP made a very uninformed assumption that this is PHP code, that's too bad, but don't edit to change the meaning of the entire question because of it.

Comment: @GlaciesofPacis Of course it is (My)SQL!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not PHP Code. It's MySQL.

This is a MySQL Function with

```
SET @num := 0
```

which means that the value `0` is assigned to the variable `@num` (refer to the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-equal))

This is used in

`UPDATE pop_table SET id = @num := (@num+1);`

To make it more understandable, the PHP equivalent would be:

`$num = 0;` (this is not really comparable, just to get the idea)

**UPDATE**

I was inspired by the comments to do the *NOT RECOMMENDED* PHP solution.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM pop_table ORDER BY id ASC");
$id = 0;
while($result = $mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $id++
    mysql_query("UPDATE pop_table SET id = " . $id . " WHERE id=" . $result["id"]);
}
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `pop_table` AUTO_INCREMENT =1;");
```

didn't test it, but should work.

Comment: Ok, so when when I remove this snippet the remaining file (called optimizedb.php) does work, albeit without performing the specific task this particular code was intended for... It seems clear this is a case of someone pasting a snippet they didn't understand, leaving it and never returning to fix it.  So now I just need to determine the PHP equivalent for this...

Comment: I think that this script has its own sense and you should execute it directly in MySQL, mainly because you don't need to rewrite it, but it's always faster to do things directly in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks Steve, that definitely points me in the right direction... I can think of the obvious reasons why one wouldn't typically want to reset the unique IDs of a table (references, w/foreign keys, etc.) but the table this snippet appears designed to 'fix' doesn't appear to have such references - and is whacked out - has id numbers ranging from 1 to 110009999.  It seems to dynamically update the table when features are turned on and off, creating large gaps in ID -which I presume this code was intended to 'fix'. Beyond references, is there another reason this is considered not recommended? TX

Comment: Well, i think the disadvantages are like summarized references, performance and not mentioned: when the data is changed during your queries, it could have unforseen sideeffects. if it helped you, i'd appreciate if you marked my answer as solution ;)

Comment: oh and to avoid these sideeffects you should insert `mysql_query("SET autocommit=0");` before `$query = ...` and `mysql_query("commit");` after the loop (but before the ALTER-query.

Comment: Hi, yes, you have definitely addressed both parts of the question in the deepest fashion - but I thank others as well, all answers were helpful.  I will definitely check on the autocommit to understand its effect, thanks again...

Answer (score 5):

That is SQL is := is vaiable assignment with at least MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

This is [the assignment operator used by MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-equal).

You usually can't convert MySQL code to PHP code. MySQL is used to query database tables and return data matching some criteria.

PHP is a programming language that can be used to do many things, but replacing MySQL code with PHP code (assuming you find a way to do so) would probably result in your PHP script being terribly slow.

[PHP manual](http://php.net/manual)
[MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/)

Comment: Don't know who downvoted you but the link is handy as I know very little of direct sql, but need to convert this code snippet into functional PHP... tx

Answer (score 1):

You know it's the assignment operator in Mysql already... @num is a database variable.

But what does the whole snippet do? It updates the "id" field in the whole table in a loop, to a nice incremental range, from 1 to N where N is the total number of rows: the first updated row gets the value 1, the next row 2, then 3, etc.... Finally it changes the nature of the id column to an automatically incrementing column. (That might help reset the current value of the autoincrement counter to one more than  the current maximum value, I'm not sure.)

Why do you need to  convert it to PHP? This is intended to be run only once, and just serves to clean up the database. That is all. And if you want to run it now and then, it makes no sense at all to run it outside of a database.

Comment: Hahaha yes, in a normal case you are right - but note my response to Steve above - there's something strange with this app and when I am seeing a value of 110009999 in an auto-increment / unique id set as int(11) (not sure what the limit is) with gaps of 2000+ it's concerning... for now, I just want the maintenance button to work and do as intended so they can just click it - but there are definitely more issues to address.  We will likely need to hire someone to rewrite this thing is my guess.